Deleted .so files on Android come back after a while
I have a rooted android device. Version 13. I want to delete the .so files listed below under /system/lib and /system/lib64. I can delete them and the files are indeed deleted for a while but they come back after 10-20 seconds. The files I want to delete are related to the camera hardware. Even if I don't use the camera, the files I delete come back. My camera app is currently disabled.
secret:/system/lib # find /system/lib -type f -name '*camera*'
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.common-V1-ndk.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.common@1.0.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device-V1-ndk.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.2.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.3.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.4.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.5.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.6.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.device@3.7.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata-V1-ndk.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata@3.2.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata@3.3.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata@3.4.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata@3.5.so
/system/lib/android.hardware.camera.metadata@3.6.so
/system/lib/libcamera2ndk.so
/system/lib/libcamera_algoup_jni.xiaomi.so
/system/lib/libcamera_client.so
/system/lib/libcamera_ispinterface_jni.xiaomi.so
/system/lib/libcamera_metadata.so
/system/lib/libcamera_mianode_jni.xiaomi.so
/system/lib/vendor.mediatek.hardware.camera.isphal@1.0.so

